# How do I use window.location.assign() as soon as the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, browser, redirect

Using `window.location.assign()` doesn't add to the browser history if you do it as soon as the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    location.assign('page.html'); // Same behavior as .replace()
});
```

However, using `window.location.assign()` after a short delay does add a new history entry. The user can press the back button to return to the original page.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {location.assign('page.html')}, 1000); // Browser loads new page to history log
});
```

How do I use `window.location.assign()` in `$(document).ready()` immediately and make it add the destination page as a new entry into the browser history?

Comment: Try `$( window ).on( "load", function() { location.assign('page.html') })` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(window).on('load', function(){})` to assign the location. The `$(document).ready` event occurs when the HTML document has been loaded, and the window.onload event occurs later, when all content has been loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("document ready "+Date.now());
});
$(window).load(function(){
  console.log("window loaded  "+Date.now());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```